# While loop not running the last loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, while-loop, card

Im writing a card game where I need to play the game war. For now I just want the while loop to loop until someone reaches 0 cards (arr.length = 0) so essentially one player should have 52 cards and the other 0. But on the last loop the last 2 cards are always stuck in the array Im popping them into for evaluation. Is there a problem with my while logic?

```
class Card {
  constructor(suit, rank, score) {
    this.suit = suit
    this.rank = rank
    this.score = score
  }    
}

class Player {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.hand = []
    
  }

class Table {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.p1CurrentCard = []
    this.p2CurrentCard = []
  }
  
}


class Deck {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.deckLength = 52
    this.cards = []
    this.suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"];
    this.ranks = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"];
    this.scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
  }
  
  generateDeck() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.suits.length; i++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < this.ranks.length; x++) {
        let genCard = new Card(this.suits[i], this.ranks[x], this.scores[x]);
        this.cards.push(genCard)
      }
    }
  }
  shuffle() {
    let shuffledCardsLength = this.cards.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < shuffledCardsLength; i++) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffledCardsLength);
      let placeholderDeck = this.cards[i];
      this.cards[i] = this.cards[j];
      this.cards[j] = placeholderDeck;
    }
  }
  deal() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i += 2) {
      P1.hand.push(this.cards[i]);
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < this.cards.length; i += 2) {
      P2.hand.push(this.cards[i]);
    }
    
  }
  
 
  playCard() {
    TB.p1CurrentCard.unshift(P1.hand.pop());
    TB.p2CurrentCard.unshift(P2.hand.pop());
  }

  checkCards() {
    while (P1.hand.length > 0 && P2.hand.length > 0) {
      {
        if ((TB.p1CurrentCard[0].score) > (TB.p2CurrentCard[0].score)) {
          P1.hand.unshift(TB.p2CurrentCard.pop());
          P1.hand.unshift(TB.p1CurrentCard.pop());
        }
        else if ((TB.p1CurrentCard[0].score) < (TB.p2CurrentCard[0].score)) {
          P2.hand.unshift(TB.p1CurrentCard.pop());
          P2.hand.unshift(TB.p2CurrentCard.pop());
        }
        else if ((TB.p1CurrentCard[0].score) === (TB.p2CurrentCard[0].score)) {
          P1.hand.unshift(TB.p2CurrentCard.pop());
          P1.hand.unshift(TB.p1CurrentCard.pop());
          console.log("Its a tie!");
        }
      }
      this.playCard();
    }
  }
}
  

const MD = new Deck("MainDeck");
const P1 = new Player("PlayerOne");
const P2 = new Player("PlayerTwo");
const TB = new Table("Tabletop")

MD.generateDeck();

MD.shuffle();

MD.deal()

// console.log(P1.hand)
// console.log(P2.hand)

MD.playCard()
MD.checkCards()


// console.log(TB.p1CurrentCard)
// console.log(TB.p2CurrentCard)

console.log(TB.p1CurrentCard.length)
console.log(TB.p2CurrentCard.length)
console.log(P1.hand.length)
console.log(P2.hand.length)
```

Comment: Possibly the problem is you still call `playCard()` even in the possibility that someone has 0 cards. I'll provide an answer to get around that.

Comment: Ahh thats not it at all. It has to do with your `unshift()` and `pop()` inside the while loop.

Comment: Not sure I follow the difference between `hand` vs `card` in this context.  Also, looks like `currentCard` is an array, but doesnt' seem like it should be.  Can you also include the setup conditions like showing what the values of `P1.hand`, etc. are and what you expect that value to be?

Comment: Also, FYI - you have two back-to-back brackets in your while loop `while () {{ }}` - not sure if this is intentional, but likely impacts your expectations around `this.playCard()`

Comment: I added all of my objects as well, sorry if the code is unclean i just started learning JS